# How to break a string literal across multiple lines of source code in Java?

Tags: java

I have done C++ in the past and to continue with a long line of code I would use the:

```
\
```

operator. My compiler does not seem to recognize that in Java (obviously). What command do I use for next line *within* the code itself, *not* the output.

Edit: example -

```
System.out.println("This code os too long to be put in one extremely long line of code so that is why I am asking this question\nThanks!");
```

Error: 
1 error found:
File: H:\CISS 110\BarakGasPrice.java  [line: 12]
Error: String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

Comment: Just write on the next line. Blanks are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: @ernest_k still does not work for some reason...I am using Drjava

Comment: @FaridB: The single line of code in the question does not produce the error in the question.  So that doesn't really clarify.

Comment: If you are using eclipse format your code Ctrl+Shit+F in windows

Answer (score 1):

Break the string at a sensible spot and concatenate the two strings together.

```
System.out.println("This code os too long to be put in one extremely long " +
                   "line of code so that is why I am asking this question\nThanks!");
```